# SQL Searching not working form a particular starting element only 'a' and 'e'

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code

```
SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE name = 'a%' AND name = 'e%';
```

but I'm getting error

so, how to display records in the table which is **starting** from **a** and **e**?

This is my error:- `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''a%' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1`

this is my table structure:- https://prnt.sc/ua0zvb

so, please help me...

Comment: Do you mean name should start with a or e only, or should name start with a, b, c, d or e?

Comment: I don't see an error in your syntax.  However, the code is not going to do what you want because you are confusing `=` with `like`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `like` operator

```
SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE name like 'a%' or name  like 'e%'
```

Comment: First it should be `or` instead of `and`. And the original query should work anyway

Comment: I will try also this query, But not working.

in this case, not show any record.

Answer (score 0):

To get the rows where name starts with an `a` or an `e`:

Use `substr()` to get the first character.

```
SELECT * FROM `contacts` where substr(name, 1) in ('a', 'e')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Substr`

SELECT * from employees where SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME,1) between 'A' and 'e'

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has `regexp`, which makes this quite simple:

```
WHERE name regexp '^[ae]'
```

Regular expressions are very powerful.  This is a very simple example:

```
'^[ae]'
-^ the "^" means the pattern must begin at the beginning of name
--^ this is a character class that matches either a or e
```